# Home and Categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Alright so I am building a photo sharing application that lets users sign up and post photos. As soon as users are signed up they are redirected to the home page with this button.[image]

Any pictures uploaded will be posted on the homepage. I wanted to make a much easier and organized way for users to upload photos based on what it was related to so I made a categories tab shown below.
[image]

once clicked on they will be greeted with these buttons. Which I want people to click on and be redirected to what ever button clicked on and be greeted with the upload a photo button again but any photo that is uploaded will be only seen in that specific category.

[image]

And that is pretty much where I am stuck at the moment. I tried creating a root for the specific categories but that did not work. Can someone help me figure this thing through, thanks.

Comment: what means, that you created a root?

Comment: What I meant by that was I tried to create a root that redirect users to the page that the users clicked on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to create action index on categories controller (categories is your resource here).

Therefore when action index is displayed, you need to show user "upload a photo button" and in controller create photo in specific category like:

```
@category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
@category.photos.create!(params[:photo])
```

Of course you need a relation between categories and photo (probably one-to-many).

Comment: I don't have a controller for categories generated yet, how may I do that? All I want my category page to do it to allow users to click on what ever category they want, than that Will redirect them to the page they chose and be greeted with an upload button, if you want a copy of my project to make more sense you can leave your email and I can send it to you.

Comment: Therefore you need to create categories controller - categories are resource in your application. You can actually read a lot about it here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions